# Indian e-visa: where is the immigration office located on Delhi airport?

Tags: airports, india, e-visas, new-delhi

I'm arriving at the Delhi airport with e-visa. I'm not going to leave the airport because I will take a domestic flight to a small airport in few hours. I have to have my visa confirmed before I will take the domestic flight.

In order to confirm my visa, I wonder where is the immigration office located on this huge airport. Do I have to walk around and find it, or is it just on the way leaving my terminal?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "confirmed"? If you were issued e-visa, there is nothing else to do but print a copy and bring it with you.

Comment: Well, e-visa doesn't allow you to enter India. The entry can be refused by the immigration office.

Comment: Warning: the confirmation mail which seems like an evisa is not the e-visa. It is a useless document they send to your email. You must go again to evisa website, and retrieve your evisa (which should have the photo).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I have the document you mentioned (Electronic Travel Authorization), it has the photo, bar codes and it explicitly says it doesn't guarantee entry to India.

Comment: You are not guaranteed entry to any country, even with a visa. That's just how international travel works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to find the immigration center. You will leave your gate and head down a long corridor. You will than be routed down an escalator and into the room with the immigration desks. You will see sculptures of large hands coming out of the wall.  Be prepared to present your evisa and your passport. You will also have to provide a destination address.[image: route leading to immigration center here]

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear from your question whether you have experience flying internationally or not.

When you arrive at an international airport on a passenger flight from another country, *everybody* on the plane (even the crew) has to go through immigration. After leaving the plane, you will follow corridors and signs and will be directed toward the immigration desk. There you will usually find huge queues of people (or at least *space* for huge queues of people, if you're lucky and it isn't busy) where everybody will need to talk to an immigration officer before proceeding to wherever they are going next.

It will be basically impossible (and a serious breach of security) to "miss" going through immigration.

A quick Google search shows that the immigration desk in Delhi looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: I have some experience but not enough experience. IFAIK, the airport is some kind of international ground where I can move without visa. To rephrase my question, I doubt I can miss the immigration while moving to the domestic departure.

Comment: @MazeGen: You are right. You cannot miss it. Immigration is not optional.

Comment: The airport is divided in zones. You cannot pass from international to domestic without control (or the control will be useless). Check with your airline about the baggage: you may need to get them, pass the custom and recheck (often at a transfer desk near the collection of baggage)

Comment: Well, @GregHewgill , the picture shows the _room_ (e-Visa lines are now on the other side), but in reality _there are about one hundred million people waiting in lines_. At least that is what it feels like....